# linqtotwitter get tweets without video

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to get tweets by using linqtotwitter with c#  and there is a task to get 10 last tweets without video content.
 firstly I have retrieved last 10 statuses like this:

```
var srch = Enumerable.SingleOrDefault((from search in
                                    twitterContext.Search
                                        where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                                           search.Query == hashTag &&
                                           search.Count == 10
                                        select search));
```

and  secondly I am trying to exclude tweets with video content:

```
    var result = srch.Statuses.ToList()
                  .Where(item => item.Entities.MediaEntities.
                            Where(innerItems => innerItems.VideoInfo.Duration == 0)); // shows error
```

`status` contains`entities` collection, where each `entity` contains `mediaentities` collection, where each `mediaEntity` has `videoInfo` property. 
But there is some difficulty to compose a correct linq query to a such complex structure like `statuses` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to familiarize yourself with linq. Nevertheless here's what you're probably looking for:

```
var srch = twitterContext.Search
            .FirstOrDefault(search => 
                search.Type == SearchType.Search && 
                search.Query == hashTag);

var srchWithoutVideo = srch?.Statuses?.Where(status =>
                status.Entities.MediaEntities.All(entity => entity.VideoInfo.Duration == 0))
            .OrderByDescending(status => status.CreatedAt)
            .Take(10);
```

I'm guessing at your intended result - Move the count out of the search. I think you may want all the tweets first by the hashTag and then in the second query you can filter, order by CreatedAt Descending and take 10.